# Edited and Deleted hangout chat messages are not sent to bots

Tags: hangouts-api, google-hangouts

Hangout Chat is sending only new messages to the Bot, edits and deletes are not being sent and there is no info either in the documentation https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events

Another issue is, bot's getting message only when its mentioned in a room, all other messages are not sent to bot.

How can i resolve/work around these issues?

Comment: To interact without a user mention to the bot, you’ll need to direct message the bot. You can also submit feature requests to google to hopefully get the above functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

Hangouts Chat bots is only sent new messages. Edited messages don't get sent to the bot. Though as Brett mentioned you can submit a feature request if you can think of use cases for the functionality (see below).

I suggest checking the [Hangouts Chat API support page](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/support) and [search whether someone's filed a feature request (FR)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:350158%2B%20type:feature_request) on Google's issue tracker. If so, star it and add a link to it here via a comment. If not, [file a new feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215) and also link it here so others can vote on it.

As for the purpose of @mentioning a bot in rooms, this is likely done for privacy/security purposes. Having a bot or bots always listening to conversations in a room could raise such concerns. I'd expect bots to only get messages when it is directly @mentioned in a room unless Google feels otherwise. Who knows... may be if enough people star it, they may consider it.